# UserDefaults.standard no funciona correctamente con variables String

Tags: swift, string, swift3

Que tal estoy teniendo problemas con un pequeño código..
Estoy intentando guardar un `String` con `UserDefaults.standard`

```
private static let KEY : String = "KEY"
private static let NOMBRE : String = "Usuario"

let prefs = UserDefaults.standard
prefs.setValue(NOMBRE, forKey: KEY)

print(prefs.string(forKey: KEY)!)
```

y el resultado de mi print es `nil`

Y sólo tengo problemas con los `Strings`
Por que no puedo guardar una variable de tipo `String` ?

Comment: Si lo estas ejecutando en `Playground`, existe ese bug, de que no lo guarda. Te deberia correr bien este codigo usando un  device o simulador. Y te recomiendo trata de no usar `!` para acceder al optional, mas bien utiliza [Optional unwrapping](https://medium.com/@wilson.balderrama/what-are-optionals-in-swift-3-b669ca4c2f12#.o0ikxeq6c).

Answer (score 1):

El código siguiente (que es el mismo que el tuyo) funciona perfectamente:

```
let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
userDefaults.setValue("Hola", forKey: "key")

print(userDefaults.string(forKey: "key"))
```

Y lo que sale por consola es:

> Optional("Hola")

Por otro lado, has de tener en cuenta que hay un bug conocido (pero no documentado) con el simulador de `iOS 10`. Si ejecutas el simulador de `iOS 8/9` anterior a `iOS 10` por alguna razón no funciona correctamente. Una forma de solucionarlo es reiniciar el Mac y ejecutar solamente el simulador de `iOS 10`. Otros usuarios han tenido problemas solo por tener instalados varios simuladores.
Si los problemas persisten, reinicia el simulador mediante `Simulator` -> `Reset Content and Settings`

Comment: Si al parecer se tiene un bug lo probé de nuevo y funciona correctamente, de todas formas gracias x tu respuesta.